# Examples of Asynchronous Interaction in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, delegates, callback

I know that it's possible to implicitly provide asynchronous interaction using:

- Asynchronous Delegates
- Asynchronous Callbacks

I was just wondering what other methods .Net supports for asynchronous interaction?

Help greatly appreciated.

Regards

EDIT:

Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly....
I UNDERSTAND THREADING AND CONCURRENCY PERFECTLY, I simply wanted a list of potential ways to implement asychronous interaction in .Net, aside from using asynchronous delegates or callbacks.

Comment: I've seen some badly worded questions on here, but this takes the biscuit!

Comment: How is this even complex?
If I asked the question, give me a list of ways to store data on a portable medium other than using a CD, you would reply with: A USB Stick, a floppy disk etc.
All i wanted was a list of the supported methods for asynchronous interaction in .Net.......not rocket science!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am not sure I entirely understand what you aim for in your question, but I'll give it a shot)

For allowing asynchronous code execution in winforms applications the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component is rather convinient. I also often use the [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) method as a simple way to spawn a method on its own thread.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this web page, its nicely written with good examples:
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/

Answer (score 0):

This might be outside what you're asking, but there is also support for Message Queueing.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous operations in .NET are started by calling a method that is named `BeginSomething`, where `Something` is probably going to be `Invoke`, `Write`, `Send` or some other operation.

Example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginsend.aspx

You pass a delegate of your own that will be executed when the operation completes. You can then get the result of the operation by calling a corresponding method `EndSomething`.

Example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.endsend(VS.80).aspx

The pattern is *usually* the same regardless of the operation being performed. There are oddities where the `EndSomething` method is named something inconsistent instead.

More examples:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.imetadataexchange.beginget.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetresponse.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you could base Expression tress or other monads (not yet allow to link but the term can be found wiki and Calvin has a great blog on the subject as well)

basically everything that allows you to make imparative coding can be used for asyncrounous implementations.

You could also google on continuation passing. A style of coding where all methods do not return values (void) but take a parameter (a delegate of sorts) telleing it what to execute when done.